# Succulent Plant identification

Tags: species-identification, botany

Can anyone identify this succulent plant?
Location: Tamil Nadu,India

[image]

Comment: This looks possibly like a species of Sansevieria, also known as Snake Plant. Perhaps Sansevieria parva or Sansevieria dooneri. Parva is usually much darker in colour than dooneri, but it's difficult to tell in the photo. Both are perennials that can be found in India.